# After updating node getting error MethodNotAllowedError

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

After updating node i m getting error:

> {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"GET is not allowed"}

node version@ 4.4.3

webpack version@ 1.13.0

webpack-dev-server version@ 1.14.0

OS Window 8

Comment: did you rebuild your dependencies?

Comment: yes I tried rebuilding dependency, but not working.